# How do I delete pointer to (struct/object) without destroying pointers inside (struct/object)?

Tags: c++, object, pointers, struct

If I have a pointer to a struct/object, and that struct/object contains two other pointers to other objects and I want to delete the "object that contains the two pointers without destroying the pointers it holds" - how do I do that?

Pointer to Object A (Contains Pointer to Object B, Contains Pointer to Object C).
Delete Object A
Pointer to Object A is deleted, Pointer to Object B / C does still exists.

Is there something that I have to do to make this work?

**UPDATE**

It's for a game project, I hope this explains it. Right now, I have some "problems" even putting the two pointers to B, C inside the first Struct (A)

```
struct Player
{
    char * Name;
    Weapon* PlayerWeapon;
    Armor* PlayerArmor;
};

struct Weapon
{
    char * Name;
    int Damage;
};

struct Armor
{
    char * Name;
    int Resistance;
};
```

And this somehow doesn't work.

```
Player* CreatePlayer(char * Name, Weapon* weapon, Armor* armor)
{
    Player *pPlayer = new Player;

    pPlayer->Name = name;
    pPlayer->Weapon = weapon;
    pPlayer->Armor = armor;
};
```

And later when a player "dies", the equipment should not be deleted.

Comment: We need more details. Are members destroyed in struct's destructor?

Comment: Have you actually tried to do this and come across some problems? Because deleting a struct will not call delete on any pointers it contains.

Comment: Who *owns* B and C? What decides when they should be deleted?

Comment: Game Project, a player/enemy holds equipment until they get "destroyed", although that doesn't say that the equipment gets destroyed.

Comment: Btw, all the code you show, does what you want as far as it goes. Deleting a player does not delete their weapon. If your program "doesn't work", you'll need to ask another question about whatever it is that goes wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The pointers (B & C) contained inside the pointer (A) will not be deleted unless you explicitly do it through your destructor. But you cant use the pointer A to access B & C once you delete the pointer A.

Note: You should be having a copy constructor and = overloaed operator in your class A to avoid shallow copying.

If you want to use the same armor and the weapon for someother player make sure you are not deleting the weapon and armor in your players destructor. Then you can use the same pointers for another player like this.

```
Weapon* weapon = CreateWeapon();
Armor* armor   = CreateArmor();

Player* player1 = CreatePlayer("Alpha", weapon, armor);
delete player1;

Player* player2 = CreatePlayer("Beta", weapon, armor);
delete player2;
```

Comment: If the struct doesn't own the objects pointed to, perhaps you *want* shallow copying. Or no copying at all.

Comment: Updated my post, please see my example.

Comment: @Deukalion: Not sure how you are saying the weapon is deleted when the player is deleted? are you releasing the memory of the weapon in the destructor of the player?

Comment: I am not saying anything, I'm asking what to do. If I have an object "Enemy" instead of "Player" and the enemy dies in the game, he also carries a weapon and an armour those should not be deleted when the game calls Destroy(Player* player) or Destroy(Enemy* enemy); Those items, should lie on the ground after an enemy is slain and therefor the pointers to those items should not be deleted. But the Enemy should be deleted.

Comment: @Deukalion: Don't delete the Weapon in the destructor of Player. Then it remains alive. But you cant access it with the player object.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Foo
{
   A *a;
   B *b;
}

Foo *foo = new Foo();
delete foo; //foo now points to garbage. you can't use it
foo = nullptr; //don't use foo!
```

But you can do so:

```
Foo *foo new Foo();
//do some stuff with foo
A *a = foo->a;
B *b = foo->b;
delete foo;
foo = nullptr;
// if Foo does not destroy objects pointed by a,b in destructor you can still
//use them through a,b vars
a->doSomeStuff(); //ok
b->doSomeOtherStuff(); //ok
```

**EDIT**

In your case armor and weapon are not destroyed. You just lose pointers to them (and get the memeory leak). I suggest you to hold all your armor and weapons in some containers (like `std::vector`) to keep the pointers

Comment: Updated my post, please see my example.

Answer (score 1):

> Pointer to Object A (Contains Pointer to Object B, Contains Pointer to
>   Object C). Delete Object A Pointer to Object A is deleted, **Pointer to
>   Object B / C does still exists?**

**No**, they are in **undefined state**. Anything can happen to them. May be in your system, you notice that they are existent, but assume it's just an illusion, which is not guaranteed every time.

As soon as, you delete `A*`, all it's content are available for next dynamic allocation. Possibly they might get allocated to some other object later on. Some system, may `0` out everything which is deleted. Again, anything can happen!

> Is there something that I have to do to make this work?

Store `B*` and `C*` to other pointers before deleting `A*`.Then it's perfectly ok, because objects are intact and you have its addresses stored.

Comment: Just to emphasize: the objects `B` and `C` still exist, but the *pointers* to them that are part of the body of `A`, do not exist. Other pointers to the same object do still exist, which is why the thing to do is to copy the pointer before deleting `A`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible without making a copy of a and b first.

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid using "naked" pointers. It's better to use a smart pointer class such as `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`. They take care of `new` and `delete`, which are very tricky to get completely right unassisted. These are found in Boost, and `shared_ptr` is also in the TR1 library (`std::tr1::`) that probably came with your compiler, or just in plain `std::` if your compiler is more recent.

Although you haven't said much about the program, if it's necessary to do something preserve the pointers, it sounds like the object `A` has the only copy of the pointers to B and C. That is a job for `unique_ptr`.

In C++11,

```
struct A_type {
    std::unique_ptr< B_type > B; // Object *owns* B and C
    std::unique_ptr< C_type > C;
};

std::unique_ptr< A_type > A( new A_type );

auto my_B = std::move( A->B ); // Acquire ownership away from object
auto my_C = std::move( A->B );
A.release(); // Delete object and anything it owns (at this point, nothing)

// my_B and my_C are guaranteed to be destroyed at some appropriate time
```

Comment: Presumably, if he doesn't want to delete the pointers, it is because they are used for navigation, and not ownership.  (In my experience, this is usually the case.)  Using `shared_ptr` for this will result in cycles, and using `unique_ptr` simply doesn't work.

Comment: @James: aha! "navigation and not ownership", good phrase. When I have this argument, I talk about how raw pointers can be used to define "structure", which is less clear than "navigation". The next phase of the argument seems to be "well, then use `weak_ptr`, because clearly the fix for too many smart pointers is to add more smart pointers" ;-)

Comment: @JamesKanze But in that case, he wouldn't have arrived at the concern about preserving them before the object gets destroyed, because some other navigation path would exist. That was the first thing I thought of before writing the answer. For a random graph, `shared_ptr` with `weak_ptr` to break cycles is the generic recommendation. Anyway, the question (as written when I answered) was very vague.

Comment: @Potatoswatter If you need `weak_ptr`, then you shouldn't be using `shared_ptr`.  Determining which pointers have to be weak is more difficult than managing the memory completely by hand.  (Also, a lot of navigation involves pointers in vectors or maps.  Using `weak_ptr` doesn't remove the entry in the vector or the map, which ultimately leads to memory leaks.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Well, it depends. The last program I wrote with a complicated graph stored it as a list of cycles, but there were no smart pointers. Anyway, as I said, the original question somewhat indicated the task wasn't "navigation". Now the updated question seems to show a fundamental misunderstanding of what pointers are — he's expecting `unique_ptr` behavior despite having a naked pointer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter The update shows that he definitely does _not_ want the behavior of `unique_ptr`; that the lifetime of the pointed to `Armor` and `Weapon` is independent of that of the `Player`.

Comment: @JamesKanze On the contrary, there's still not enough information. For example, if the armor is a randomly-generated, unique object that can be dropped, and the reason it's not destroyed when the player dies is that it drops automatically, and it's owned by whatever contains or uses it, then `unique_ptr` should be used to transfer from the player to e.g. a tile of the playing field.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Reread the question.  He specifically said that `Armor` and `Weapon` should _not_ be deleted when `Player` is deleted.  `unique_ptr` can only be considered a error in this case, and `shared_ptr` smells of an anti-pattern.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'd still prefer `unique_ptr` over a raw pointer when ownership is involved, even if it should be transferred before destruction. A class inheriting from `unique_ptr` and logging error on improper deletion, or a custom deleter implementing whatever protocol (say, object must be serialized to save-file or network or there's an error) would be the way. But leaving ownership implicit makes debugging hard and opens the way to memory leaks.